# Audio Processing - Tone Recognition

Tags: c++, audio, signal-processing

I've started developing a simple guitar tuner as a learning project for audio processing programs.

Could someone recommend me an adequate library for this? Here's basically what I'm looking for:

- Microphone input.
- Real-time processing of the signal. I need to be able to perform note recognition on whatever is being played to the mic.
- Cross platform/open source would be a huge plus.

Comment: Similar question at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466968/real-time-pitch-detection-using-fft](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466968/real-time-pitch-detection-using-fft).

Comment: You might want to tag this DSP as well.

Answer (score 4):

[FFT Guitar Tuner](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/FftGuitarTuner.aspx).