# Recognising guitar input tone from mic

Tags: python, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recognising tone of the audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797631/recognising-tone-of-the-audio)

Hi I need to recognize what tone is being played on my mic which inputs in the pc from the mic, with python. What should I use?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797631/recognising-tone-of-the-audio