# How to recognize a musical tone in Android?

Tags: android, audio

I'm developing an Android application, what that i need is recognize a musical tone, for example, if you took my guitar and you played a **C** I would like my application was able to tell me the note that I played.

The basic operation would be simple, and the sound from the microphone recorded through some sort of recognition would have the output of which I need.

The only one thing that i don't know is: it is possible do this ?

If is yes, is it possible recognize more than one notes over a period of time?

Comment: See this code: https://code.google.com/p/android-guitar-tuner/source/browse/trunk/src/com/example/GuitarTuner/FFT.java?r=2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible? Certainly. There are already apps on the store that do this: [Take this for example](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.cohortor.gstringsng). As for how to do it, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797631/recognising-tone-of-the-audio?rq=1) might lead you in the right direction, and here's the text for that question:

To recognize the frequency of an audio signal, you would use the FFT ([Fast Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)) algorithm. As far as I can tell, PyGame has no means to record audio, nor does it support the FFT transform.

First, you need to capture the raw sampled data from the sound card; this kind of data is called PCM (Pulse Code Modulation). The simplest way to capture audio in Python is using the [PyAudio library](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) (Python bindings to PortAudio). [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) can also do it, it's probably an overkill for your purposes. Capturing 16-bit samples at a rate of 48000 Hz is pretty typical and probably the best a normal sound card will give you.

Once you have raw PCM audio data, you can use the `fftpack` module from the [scipy library](http://www.scipy.org/) to run the samples through the FFT transform. This will give you a *frequency distribution* of the analysed audio signal, i.e., how strong is the signal in certain frequency bands. Then, it's a matter of finding the frequency that has the strongest signal.

You *might* need some additional filtering to avoid [harmonic frequencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic) I am not sure.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Good point. I've edited my answer with the text from the answer I linked.

Comment: Wow, it's a really nice answer now. You, sir, deserve an upvote !