# FFT Pitch Detection for iOS using Accelerate Framework?

Tags: objective-c, ios, signal-processing, fft, accelerate-framework

I have been reading up on FFT and Pitch Detection for a while now, but I'm having trouble piecing it all together.

I have worked out that the Accelerate framework is probably the best way to go with this, and I have read the example code from apple to see how to use it for FFTs. What is the input data for the FFT if I wanted to be running the pitch detection in real time? Do I just pass in the audio stream from the microphone? How would I do this?

Also, after I get the FFT output, how can I get the frequency from that? I have been reading everywhere, and can't find any examples or explanations of this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This question contains a lot of detailed information, helped me a lot when I needed to implement a pitch extraction function. [Using the apple FFT and accelerate Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398753/using-the-apple-fft-and-accelerate-framework)

Comment: possible duplicate of [FFT on iPhone to ignore background noise and find lower pitches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181630/fft-on-iphone-to-ignore-background-noise-and-find-lower-pitches)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Frequency and pitch are not the same thing - frequency is a physical quantity, pitch is a psychological percept - they are similar, but there are important differences, which may or may not matter to you, depending on the type of instrument for which you are trying to measure pitch.

You need to read up a little on the various pitch detection algorithms (and on the meaning of pitch itself), decide what algorithm you want to use and only *then* set about implementing it. See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection) for a good overview of [pitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_%28music%29) and pitch detection (note that you can use FFT for the autocorrelation-based and frequency domain methods).

As for using the FFT to identify peaks in a spectrum and their associated frequencies, there are many questions and answers related to this on SO already, see for example: [How do I obtain the frequencies of each value in an FFT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364823/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result/4371627#4371627)

Answer (score 3):

I have an example implementation of an Autocorrelation function available online for ios 5.1. Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11042610/1457445) for a link to the implementation AND functions on how to find the nearest note and how to create a string representing the pitch (A, A#, B, B#, etc...)

While the FFT is very useful in many applications, it might not be the most accurate if you're trying to do simple pitch detection. (It can be as accurate, but you have to deal with complex numbers to do a lot of phase calculations)